# How to pass credentials into `file_get_html` using simplehtmldom

Tags: php

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786067/simple-html-dom-code-issue/)

I'm looking to use `file_get_html` to get a div from another website into mine. This is for a game website to get the latest relevent post. The problem is that their website requires authentication. Is there a way I can programatically authenticate via php and allow the correct page to be returned when using `file_get_html`?

Comment: Try using cURL, if you have to pass credentials.

Comment: How can I? I've also added the previous question link at the top.

Comment: @user3902158, check out chat